# How do I set up a JSON file to configure nlogging

Tags: c#, json, nlog

My current project at work requires all config files to be in JSON including my config.log file meaning I am not permitted to use the automatically generated .xml with the nlog.config nuget package. I've looked at the nlog docs on github but they've been no help to me as I am still fairly new to nlog or logging in general.

Comment: Think this is still in progress, but very slow: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1588

Answer (score 2):

This is a new feature, introduced **NLog.Extensions.Logging >= 1.5.0**

below sample shows how to load NLog configuration from appsettings.json.

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
   .SetBasePath(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
   .Build();

LogManager.Configuration = new NLogLoggingConfiguration(config.GetSection("NLog"));
```

For more details check the documentation from https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/Json-NLog-Config

Answer (score 1):

As @Rolf mentioned, this isn't possible yet. The feature request is [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1588) and still open.

Currently you could configure NLog from XML or from code (e.g. C#)